# How to run Python unittest with constructor parameters?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a base class `Integration` that includes common variables for the classes that inherit from it. The class inherits from `unittest.TestCase`.

```
import unittest

class Integration(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_token, config=None):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.api_token = api_token
        self.config = config
```

I have several classes that inherit from `Integration` class, for example:

```
class JFrogIntegration(Integration):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_token, config):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.api_token = api_token
        self.config = config
```

The class `JFrogIntegration` includes several test cases.

I want to be able to run all the tests inside `JFrogIntegration` from my `main` module. I tried with specifying the module name like so:

```
unittest.main(module='integrations.jfrog_integration')
```

However, I'm getting an error that initializing `JFrogArtifactory` requires positional parameters. I tried using `argv` parameter of `unittest.main` but that did not work.

How to get around this?